# What is the sum notation equivalent to this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I tried to solve this question

**Find radius of convergence of the series**
$$1+ \frac{a.b}{1.c}z + \frac{a(a+1)b(b+1)}{1.2...c(c+1)}z^2+.... $$

**The book answer is  1**

I cant obtain the nth term in the series ?

Comment: There is a notation that you can find helpful:
$$(x)_n=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-k)$$

Comment: Is $a.b = a\cdot b$ or do you mean it's $a\cdot (a + 1)\cdot(a + 2) ...(b - 1)\cdot b$.  I don't quite understand your notation.  It looks like those coefficients could be written with factorials.

Comment: NO a.b = a×b ordinary multiplication

Comment: @HamadaAl So $1.c=1\times c$ and $1.2...c(c+1)=1\times2\times\ldots\times c\times(c+1)$, right?

Comment: Then how do you go from $1\cdot c$ to $1\cdot 2 ... c\cdot (c + 1)$?  That looks like it should just be a factorial, but the first term doesn't look right.

Comment: @Jared That's what I'm thinking about, too. I think he means $1\times2\times\ldots\times c$.

Comment: it is right @SanathDevalapurkar

Comment: @HamadaAl Then see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is my best guess based on your notation (I think this is correct):

It goes from $a$ to $a(a + 1)$ and then, presumably to $a(a + 1)(a + 2)$, etc. and likewise for $b$.  So that's simple to write--it's part of a factorial:

$$
a(a + 1)(a + 2)...(a + n) = \frac{(a + n)!}{(a - 1)!}
$$

Then, again, likewise for $b$ and $c$ (except $c$ is on the bottom), then, in addition, you have an $n!$ on the bottom (with the $c$):

$$
\frac{(c - 1)!}{(a - 1)!(b - 1)!}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(a - 1 + n)!(b - 1 + n)!}{n!(c - 1 + n)!}z^n
$$

(note that when $i = 0$, the factorials give $(a - 1)!$, $(b - 1)!$, and $(c - 1)!$ which all cancel with the coefficient on the outside)

To find the convergence, you would just use the ratio test:

$$
\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} = \frac{(a + n)(b + n)}{(n + 1)(c + n)}z
$$

Take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$:

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(a + n)(b + n)}{(n + 1)(c + n)}z = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2}z = z 
$$

This zeries definitely converges when $|z| < 1$ (by the ratio test).  However, you now need go back and check $z = 1$ and $z = -1$.  I think it would diverge here but it may depend on the value of $a$, $b$, and $c$ (if the coefficients go to zero, then it converges when $z = -1$ by the alternating series test).

Comment: thanks , but $\frac{(a+n)(b+n)}{(n+1)(c+n)}$ .

Comment: @HamadaAl Yes, that's correct, I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$a_1=1\text{ and }\\
a_{n\forall n\geq2}=\dfrac{(a+n-1)!(b+n-1)!(c-1)!}{(n-1)!(a-1)!(b-1)!(c-n+1)!}z^{n-1},\text{ assuming $1.2...c(x-1)=1\times2\times c\times (x-1)$.}$$

Comment: but I don't think that $1.c = 1×2×....×c$

Comment: @HamadaAl But you just said that that's what it meant above!

Comment: I am so sorry 
I didn't understand you in the above comment

Comment: @HamadaAl See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of rising factorial powers (Knuth's term/notation):
$$
x^{\overline{r}} = x (x + 1) \cdots (x + r - 1)
$$
your sum seems to be:
$$
S(z)
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{a^{\overline{n}} b^{\overline{n}}}{n! c^{\overline{n}}} z^n
$$
By the ratio test:
$$
\frac{\frac{a^{\overline{n + 1}} b^{\overline{n + 1}}}{(n + 1)! c^{\overline{n + 1}}}}
     {\frac{a^{\overline{n}} b^{\overline{n}}}{n! c^{\overline{n}}}}
  = \frac{(a + n) (b + n)}{(n + 1) (c + n)}
$$
The limit of this is clearly 1, so your serie's convergence radius is 1.